# How to make valid using $$ in greasemonkey scripting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use `$$`in my new script but I don't know what lines should I add or  include.

For example:

How to use below line in greasemonkey? What should I include before?

```
$$('.steps-list li a').forEach(a => console.log(a.href))
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Please edit to clarify / add more detail.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I add an example

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about jquery?

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```